# Keeping Rows in R if Value in a Column = Value in a List

Tags: r, subset

I am fairly new to R (mostly SAS/STATA). I have a dataset (frame?) in R that I am working on and need to keep only rows that that = a value in a list of values. In SAS I would normally do something IN LIST.

This is the code to what I did so far, which does not seem to work:

```
merged2<-merge(merged1, bpa4data, by="CASE_ID")

keep<-c(745.0, 745.1, 745.2, 745.3, 745.4, 745.5, 745.6, 745.7, 745.8,     
745.9, 746.0, 746.1, 746.2, 746.3, 746.4,746.5, 746.6, 746.7, 746.8, 746.9, 
747.0, 747.1, 747.2, 747.3,747.4, 747.5, 747.6, 747.8, 747.9)

merged2[Reduce(`|`, lapply(merged2[sapply(merged2, is.numeric)], bpa4 %in%  
keep)),]
```

I get the following error:

Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'bpa4' not found.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I feel that I am using the code incorrectly since the column bpa4 is the column that would have a corresponding value in my "keep" list.

THANKS!

Comment: This may be a typo. Do you have an object named bpa4? I see bpa4data in your `merge` function.

Comment: bpa4 is the column/variable name. That is where I need the "keep"  to work i.e. look through the column and only keep rows that = one of the values in "keep". Apologies for my gross misuse of R lingo.

Comment: You want `bpa4data$bpa4` if bpa4 is a variable of bpa4data.

Comment: Floating-point equality tests are unreliable, no matter what language you're using. Also -- in any language mentioned -- you could perform a merge to do this subsetting task. Anyway, I think you'll want to post a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. .

Comment: I used the grep() to take care of the job                                                                                                        CCHD <- merged2[grep(......., merged2$bpa4),]

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `dplyr` package's `filter()` function?

```r
bpa4 = c(744.9, 745.0, 745.1)
keep = c(745.0, 745.1)
df = data.frame(bpa4)

df
#>    bpa4
#> 1 744.9
#> 2 745.0
#> 3 745.1

dplyr::filter(df, bpa4 %in% keep)
#>    bpa4
#> 1 745.0
#> 2 745.1
```

Comment: perfect answer!